# Building nested vector from map in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, hiccup

I have a set of URLs, and some of the URLs have indirect references (as a vector). Any URL that does not have an indirect reference just has `nil`. I'm starting out with the following test map:

```
{"URL 1" nil,
 "URL 2" ["indirect 1" "indirect 2"]}
```

I'm using [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) to build an HTML report, so I want this output:

```
[:div "Imports: "
 [:ul
  [:li "URL 1"]
  [:li "URL 2"]
    [:ul
     [:li "indirect 1"]
     [:li "indirect 2"]
     [:li "indirect 3"]]]]
```

I'm running into some problems returning nil when the URL does not have an indirect reference. My current code looks like this:

```
(defn list-imports
  [imports]
  (if-not (nil? imports)
    [:div "Imports: "
     [:ul
      (for [direct (keys imports)]
        [[:li direct]
         (if-let [indirects (get imports direct)]
           [:ul
             (for [indirect indirects]
               [:li indirect])]
           [:span])])]]
    [:div "Imports: none" [:br] [:br]]))
```

The problem is, it's returning this...

```
[:div
 "Imports: "
 [:ul
  ([[:li "URL 1"] [:span]]
   [[:li "URL 2"] [:ul ([:li "indirect 1"] [:li "indirect 2"])]])]]
```

I had to add in a `[:span]` tag as the case for when the indirect imports are `nil`, which I don't really want there... but otherwise, it puts in `nil` there.

The other problem is that it ends up enclosed in `()` and an extra vector, because I'm doing multiple things within the for statement. When I try to convert it with hiccup, I get `[:li "URL 1"] is not a valid element name.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a tricky aspect of building hiccup tags. Sometimes it helps to break the problem into smaller pieces.

```
(defn list-indirects
  [indirects]
  (when (seq indirects)
    [(into [:ul] (mapv (fn [i] [:li i]) indirects))]))

(defn list-imports
  [imports]
  (if (some? imports)
    [:div "Imports: "
     (into [:ul]
       (for [[url indirects] imports]
         (into [:li url] (list-indirects indirects))))]
    [:div "Imports: none" [:br] [:br]]))
```

These functions should give you the desired output.

```
(list-imports {"URL 1" nil
               "URL 2" ["indirect 1" "indirect 2"]})
=>
[:div "Imports: "
 [:ul
  [:li "URL 1"]
  [:li "URL 2"
   [:ul
    [:li "indirect 1"]
    [:li "indirect 2"]]]]]
```

This output is slightly different from your expected output, but I think it's closer to what you'd actually want i.e. the `[:li "URL 2"]` tag in your example should *contain* the `:ul` of "indirects" to be valid HTML.

Another thing to be wary of, if the order of these items is important, is that maps may not be *ordered* in the way you expect, especially once you have over a certain number of keys. When you traverse the map to build hiccup, it's possible that `"URL 2"` could come *before* `"URL 1"`. You could workaround this by using a vector of tuples, or maybe a sorted map.

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thank you so much! I guess I was trying to jam too much into one function. I didn't even think of using mapv, but it seems so obvious now :)